# Set the Value of a Hidden field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, set, hidden-field

I want to set the value of a hidden field, using JQuery.

Hidden Field:

```
<input id="chag_sort" type="hidden" name="chag_sort">
```

My JQuery:

```
 $("#input[name=chag_sort]").val(sort2);
```

What am I doing wrong? I should also mention in console that sort2 does in fact have a value: DESC.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The selector should not be `#input`. That means a field with `id="input"` which is not your case. You want:

```
$('#chag_sort').val(sort2);
```

Or if your hidden input didn't have an unique id but only a `name="chag_sort"`:

```
$('input[name="chag_sort"]').val(sort2);
```

Comment: Or, for my completionist tendencies, `$('input[name="chag_sort"]').val(sort2);`. Depending on the *type* of that `input` it might be necessary to use`$('input[name="chag_sort"]').eq(0).val(sort2);` to differentiate between the possibly-various elements sharing that name.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the hash - that's for identifying the id attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If  you have a hidden field like this

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("VertragNr") %>'/>
```

Now you can use your value like this

$(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val()