# How to store value in HTML input through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

In my HTML I have:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" id="field" value="-1"/>
</div>
```

In my jQuery I have:

```
var fieldInput = $("#field");

if(someBoolIsTrue)
    fieldInput.value = 4;
```

After this JS executes, I go to print the value of the hidden `field`, and it tells me it's still `-1`.  Am I using jQuery incorrectly here?!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The value returned from `$("#field")` is not the raw DOM node; it's a jQuery wrapper. Thus the DOM API (like the "value" property) is not directly available. You can get the DOM node out of it, or you can use jQuery APIs to do what you need.

Comment: It is frustrating when people fail to google for an answer or read the relevant documentation http://api.jquery.com/val/ + http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @Pointy You should post this as an answer. None of the other answerers cared to provide an explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the Value of a Hidden field using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998385/set-the-value-of-a-hidden-field-using-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the value like  `fieldInput.val(4);`

Another method would be `fieldInput[0].value = 4;`

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery object you have to use `val` method:

```
var fieldInput = $("#field");
if(someBoolIsTrue)
    fieldInput.val(4);
```

Or without using jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("field").value = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value in the input with id field

```
$("#field").val("your value");
```

To get the value from it ( Ex : alert the value)

```
alert($("#field").val());
```