# Assign Value for Hiddenfield in jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I assign a value for a HiddenField control in jQuery?

```
function Show(obj) {
    var Clien = $(obj).closest('tr').find("[id*=lbFare]").text();
    $(obj).parent().parent().find('[id*=pnlGrd]').show();
    $(obj).hide();

    var myHidden =  document.getElementById('<%= hdfFare.ClientID %>');
    myHidde.value = Clien;
    $('[id*=rptrbus]').find('[id*=btnSea]').show();
    var id= 0;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have a misspelled variable - `myHidde.value`

Comment: Go through this it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998385/set-the-value-of-a-hidden-field-using-jquery

Comment: Now i correct the mistake,still cant get the values

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali Already I tried the method which is given in the link.But i cannot assign the value

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Asp.net Code.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Id="hidServer"/>
```

JS Code

```
$('#hidServer').val("your value");
```